# Log4J2 Pattern Layout not picking up Pattern

Tags: maven, logging, log4j2, slf4j

I have set up a service to use SLF4J and Log4j2 but I am unable to get the specified logs in the pattern layout specified. My dependencies are:

log4j-slf4j-impl: 2.17.2
slf4j-api: 1.7.36

When I boot my service with -Dlog4j2.debug, I see the following:

```
DEBUG StatusLogger PluginManager 'Lookup' found 16 plugins
DEBUG StatusLogger null null initializing configuration org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.properties.PropertiesConfiguration@2f5ac102
DEBUG StatusLogger PluginManager 'Core' found 128 plugins
DEBUG StatusLogger PluginManager 'Level' found 0 plugins
DEBUG StatusLogger PluginManager 'Lookup' found 16 plugins
DEBUG StatusLogger Building Plugin[name=AppenderRef, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderRef].
TRACE StatusLogger TypeConverterRegistry initializing.
DEBUG StatusLogger PluginManager 'TypeConverter' found 26 plugins
DEBUG StatusLogger createAppenderRef(ref="STDOUT", level="null", Filter=null)
DEBUG StatusLogger Building Plugin[name=root, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig$RootLogger].
DEBUG StatusLogger LoggerConfig$RootLogger$Builder(additivity="null", level="INFO", levelAndRefs="null", includeLocation="null", ={STDOUT}, ={}, Configuration(PropertiesConfig), Filter=null)
DEBUG StatusLogger Building Plugin[name=loggers, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggersPlugin].
DEBUG StatusLogger createLoggers(={root})
DEBUG StatusLogger Building Plugin[name=layout, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout].
DEBUG StatusLogger PatternLayout$Builder(pattern="[%p] %d [%t] %c %M - %m%n", PatternSelector=null, Configuration(PropertiesConfig), Replace=null, charset="null", alwaysWriteExceptions="null", disableAnsi="null", noConsoleNoAnsi="null", header="null", footer="null")
DEBUG StatusLogger PluginManager 'Converter' found 45 plugins
DEBUG StatusLogger Building Plugin[name=appender, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.ConsoleAppender].
DEBUG StatusLogger ConsoleAppender$Builder(target="SYSTEM_OUT", follow="null", direct="null", bufferedIo="null", bufferSize="null", immediateFlush="null", ignoreExceptions="null", PatternLayout([%p] %d [%t] %c %M - %m%n), name="STDOUT", Configuration(PropertiesConfig), Filter=null, ={})
DEBUG StatusLogger Starting OutputStreamManager SYSTEM_OUT.false.false
DEBUG StatusLogger Building Plugin[name=appenders, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppendersPlugin].
DEBUG StatusLogger createAppenders(={STDOUT})
DEBUG StatusLogger Configuration org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.properties.PropertiesConfiguration@2f5ac102 initialized
DEBUG StatusLogger Starting configuration org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.properties.PropertiesConfiguration@2f5ac102
DEBUG StatusLogger Started configuration org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.properties.PropertiesConfiguration@2f5ac102 OK.
TRACE StatusLogger Stopping org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.DefaultConfiguration@3c69362a...
TRACE StatusLogger DefaultConfiguration notified 1 ReliabilityStrategies that config will be stopped.
TRACE StatusLogger DefaultConfiguration stopping root LoggerConfig.
TRACE StatusLogger DefaultConfiguration notifying ReliabilityStrategies that appenders will be stopped.
TRACE StatusLogger DefaultConfiguration stopping remaining Appenders.
DEBUG StatusLogger Shutting down OutputStreamManager SYSTEM_OUT.false.false-1
DEBUG StatusLogger OutputStream closed
DEBUG StatusLogger Shut down OutputStreamManager SYSTEM_OUT.false.false-1, all resources released: true
DEBUG StatusLogger Appender DefaultConsole-1 stopped with status true
TRACE StatusLogger DefaultConfiguration stopped 1 remaining Appenders.
TRACE StatusLogger DefaultConfiguration cleaning Appenders from 1 LoggerConfigs.
DEBUG StatusLogger Stopped org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.DefaultConfiguration@3c69362a OK
TRACE StatusLogger Reregistering MBeans after reconfigure. Selector=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector@5a1c3cb4
TRACE StatusLogger Using default SystemClock for timestamps.
DEBUG StatusLogger org.apache.logging.log4j.core.util.SystemClock does not support precise timestamps.
TRACE StatusLogger Using DummyNanoClock for nanosecond timestamps.
DEBUG StatusLogger Reconfiguration complete for context[name=Default] at URI jar:file:[redacted]/log4j2.properties (org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext@78e22d35) with optional ClassLoader: null
DEBUG StatusLogger Shutdown hook enabled. Registering a new one.
DEBUG StatusLogger LoggerContext[name=Default, org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext@78e22d35] started OK.
```

It looks like my file is picked with pattern: [%p] %d [%t] %c %M - %m%n

My Log4j2 Config:

```
# properties file metadata
status=error
dest=err
name=PropertiesConfig

# console appender will log to stdout
appender.consoleAppender.type=Console
appender.consoleAppender.name=STDOUT
appender.consoleAppender.target=SYSTEM_OUT
appender.consoleAppender.layout.type=PatternLayout
appender.consoleAppender.layout.pattern=[%p] %d [%t] %c %M - %m%n

# log level information
rootLogger.level=info
rootLogger.appenderRef.consoleAppender.ref=STDOUT
```

But all my logs are coming as:

`22:10:55,360 INFO  org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server          - Started @2187ms`

Comment: Can you post your log4j config?

Comment: @Lesiak Forgot that. Posted now

Comment: Jetty logging changed between version 9.x (they had a custom logging API) and 10.x (they switched to SLF4J). Which version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I saw your log4j config, and then I observed that your log4j config file may be the incorrect way.

**log4j.** must be included for each key, according to the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E29578_01/webhelp/cas_webcrawler/src/cwcg_config_log4j_file.html).

your log4j Config:

```
# properties file metadata
status=error
dest=err
name=PropertiesConfig

# console appender will log to stdout
appender.consoleAppender.type=Console
appender.consoleAppender.name=STDOUT
appender.consoleAppender.target=SYSTEM_OUT 
appender.consoleAppender.layout.type=PatternLayout
appender.consoleAppender.layout.pattern=[%p] %d [%t] %c %M - %m%n

# log level information
rootLogger.level=info
rootLogger.appenderRef.consoleAppender.ref=STDOUT
```

Updated log4j.properties Config:

```
# properties file metadata
status=error
dest=err
name=PropertiesConfig

# console appender will log to stdout
log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.target=System.out
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=[%p] %d [%t] %c %M - %m%n

# log level information
log4j.rootLogger=info,console
```

**Note:** If you are using SYSTEM_OUT in target then the warning message came on the console.

```
log4j:WARN [SYSTEM_OUT] should be System.out or System.err.
log4j:WARN Using previously set target, System.out by default.
```

in my case Pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Thanks.